# Regexport() both integers and numbers with decimals

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, re2

I'm working in Google Sheets and wondering if it's possible to use one regexport() function to export both whole and partial numbers.
I have a column with:

```
1 Ml/ 2 Ml
2 Ml/ 2.02 Ml
3 Ml/ 4.01 Ml
```

and want a column with:

```
2
2.02
4.01
```

The first value could be 2.00 as well.

I was wondering if this is possible specifically with regular expressions. I know how to do it without. I currently have `regexport(cell#, "\/\D(\d+)\D")`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need as a pattern is:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) Ml$
```

---

- `(` - 1St apture group.

  - `\d+` - One or more digits.
  - `(?:` - Open non-capture group.

    - `\.\d+` - A literal dot followed by one or more digits.
    - `)?` - Close non-capture group and make it optional.
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group.
- `Ml$` - Match "Ml" literally upto the end string ancor ($).

---

Add this to an `ARRAYFORMULA()` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3,"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) Ml$"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**without Regex**

We want to grab a value encapsulated by *slash-space* on the left and *space* on the right:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("/ ",A1)+2,FIND(" ",A1,FIND("/ ",A1)+2)-(FIND("/ ",A1)+2)))
```

[image]

*(Both Excel and Google Sheets should work the same way.  If we have to grab multiple instances, I would use **Regex**.)*

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A2, " (\d+\.\d+) Ml"), 
                   REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A2, " (\d+) Ml")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the simpler which takes care of errors and returns results as numbers at the same time.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR( 
        REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"/ (.*) ")*1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(\d[\d.]*)\s*Ml$")
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/SOwmos/1/)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\d.]*                   any character of: digits (0-9), '.' (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Ml                       'Ml'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```